# Area and second estimation from pandas graph

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series, area, threshold

[image]My x-axis data contain time in dd-mm-yy hr:min:ss with 15 minutes intervals e.g. 01/01/2010  00:00:00...01/01/2010  00:15:00 etc. The y-axis contain the corresponding signals. I would like to calculate the area above threshold values (in this case >30)from a python graph and also the corresponding x-axis value in seconds See detail in graph. I was trying to calculate with the following code. But don't think it is working. Can you please suggest me. Thanks.The threshold code looks follows:

```
 df['area']= (df['X1']>30)
 df['area'].values
#df['area'].sum
```

and the output came in true and false array.

```
[![array(\[False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False,
       False, False, False, False, False, False, False,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False, False, False,
        True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,
        True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False, False,  True,
       False, False, False, False, False, False\], dtype=bool)][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 2):

As your code is now, `df['X1']>30` will give you a boolean array.  You can use this to select the values you are interested in.

Since your data are evenly spaced, the easiest estimate of area under the curve will just be the sum of all values above your threshold times the time interval.

`area = (df[df['X1']>30] - 30).sum() * 15`

I subtracted 30, because based on your graph, you want the area above the threshold, rather than total area.  If you're interested, scipy has a number of numerical integration methods.